# padding-left inside a table

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, newsletter

I'm trying to build a newsletter which I've designed to be sent by email. I've now the problem that the text has no space to the images around it and I would like to change the `background-color` of the text field to grey just like:

[image]

If I'm giving it a new `td` is the whole code not working anymore could you help me please.

Here is the complete code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LfLR/)

```
<table width="600*" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr><br>
        <td width="201" valign="top"  >
            <img src="images/angebot1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="201" height="394"/><br />
            <br />
        </td>

        <td width="291" valign="top">
            <img src="images/angebotbild1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="335" height="150"/>
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;"></div>
            <font color="#778da7" face="Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" style="font-size: 12px"> the text </font><br><br>
            <a  href="#" alt="Book now" target="_blank" style="color:#cc1f2f; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;float:left"><img src="images/button.jpg" width="335" height="60" style="display:block;" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would recommend changing this to work without a table. There no reason this should be in a table.

Comment: the reason is that googlemail cant read div boxes or often ignore this. everytime im doing it with div boxes it will showed broke in googlemail

Comment: To move the text with `padding-left` you could wrap the text in a div and set that div with `style="padding-left: 10px;"` or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @Ruddy I disagree, Tables are still quite common practice for emails

Comment: @MackieeE The OP didn't state it was designed for an email until commenting. Read my comment under "Nasapc123" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have a little look at this.

Even for a table layout its pretty bad but we will just work with what we have.

### Padding Text:

To pad the text out we will need to wrap it in a `div`. This is due to images and so on being in the same `<td>`.

So wrap the text in:

```
<div style="padding: 10px;"></div>
```

### Changing the background:

Again as there are images in the same `<td>` that could cause problems but if the images are visible then the background will sit behind them. So it should be as simple as setting the `<td>` background like so:

```
<td style="background: #eee;" width="291" valign="top">
```

I have added a demo for you to look at. With the images it should sit correctly if not you will have to make sure the height and widths are correct to stop the background colour from showing under the images.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LfLR/4/)

### Getting rid of extra space:

The extra space is cause by the left `<td>` containing `<br /><br />` take this away and it will be fine. As this is a table `<td>` in the same `<tr>` will have the same height, changing one will affect the other.

**Before:**

```
<td width="201"valign="top">
   <img src="images/angebot1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="201" height="394" />
<br />
<br />
</td>
```

**After:**

```
<td width="201"valign="top">
   <img src="images/angebot1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="201" height="394" />
</td>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LfLR/5/)

Comment: thats how it should be . thanks ruddy , but why is there grey under the pic's.

Comment: Because thats how big both `<td>`'s are. If you put a background in the one next it you will see there the same size. So change the height.

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle the only problem i have is the color under the pics , there should be a cut. http://jsfiddle.net/9Psun/2/

is not possible to fix it ?

Comment: Updated my answer, it was `<br>` causing it.

Comment: there is still some color , even if i delete the <br>. sorry if im anoying

Comment: Look at the new demo I put up. There is no colour coming off the bottom.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. At least now you can learn from your mistakes and you will never be stuck with the same problem again!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the font tag within div.
Then add padding-left and set display: inline-block.
Also background-color can be applied to the td, as rest of the part will be covered by images.

Thanks

Comment: you mean like this ? but than hase only the text a background color but not the whole space where the text is . and if im giving it a padding left is only the first line moving to the right not the whole on http://jsfiddle.net/9Psun/  sorry i made a mistake i changed the bgcolor in the div and not in the td . if im doing it is it working with the color but under the button is also some grey. i updated the jsfiddle file and changed the color to red so that ya can see what i mean . there is some red color under the button http://jsfiddle.net/9Psun/1/

Comment: Yes, the color is due to br tags in the td where there are two images and the paragraphs. Just remove all the br(4 occurrences), then extra color at the bottom will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this is not done with a table, tables are clunky, and should never be used for layout on principle. You can use floated divs, as is shown in my example code below, allowing you to add any padding you wish, and simply updating the width of the bounding div to account for this. You should use tables for data needing to be tabulated, and rarely used in layout unless it is specifically called for due to CSS not being able to style it.

```
<div style="width:546px; margin: 0 auto;">
<a href="http://www.costakreuzfahrten.de/de/kreuzfahrten_liste/westliches_mittelmeer-savona_italien;-costa_serena-201402.html?utm_source=care&utm_medium=email&utm_content=mittelmeer&utm_campaign=4mio">
            <img src="images/head.jpg" width="536px"/></a>
<font color="#81878b" face="Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" style="font-size: 12px">
<br />Sehr geehrte Frau Muster,<br /><br />
haben Sie schon Pläne für die schönste Zeit des Jahres 2014? Wir haben ein paar verlockende 
Urlaubsideen für Sie zusammen gestellt. Eine Kreuzfahrt mit Costa ist die stilvolle Art, neue Länder, 
aufregende Metropolen und nette Menschen kennen zu lernen. Entdecken Sie die schönsten 
Plätze der Ostsee, des Orients und des Mittelmeers auf einer Kreuzfahrt mit Costa!
</font> 
    <div>
    <div style="width:201px; float:left;"  >
        <img src="images/angebot1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="201" height="394"/>                        
    </div>

    <div style="width:335px; float:left; padding-left:10px;" >
        <img src="images/angebotbild1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="335" height="150"/>
        <font color="#778da7" face="Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" style="font-size: 12px; padding:10px;">
        Wie gemacht für alle, die den etwas anderen Sommer 
        erleben wollen: Diese Reise führt Sie zu den großen 
        Metropolen und kleinen Städten des Baltikums. Jede 
        davon wird Sie durch den Kontrast zwischen prunkvoller 
        Architektur in den historischen Stadtzentren und der 
        nachhaltigen in den neuen Arealen Bauweise faszinieren. 
        Jeder Ort erzählt hier seine eigene, spannende 
        Geschichte. Lassen Sie sich verzaubern.
        </font>
        <a  href="#" alt="Book now" target="_blank" style="color:#cc1f2f; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;float:left"><img border="0"  src="images/button.jpg" width="335" height="60" style="display:block;" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if im using your way i have some space between the pics. and div boxes are not working often in mailings. i tryed it so often . googlemail oder web.de for example ignore them

Comment: This is not correct, the OP already said in the comments this is for emails. So table is the correct thing to use due to different mail clients displaying `div's` and other HTML differently. Tables are the best way to make sure the layout is correct.

Comment: Apologies for that, I must have missed where he stated this was for emails.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution you need , it will work on outlook too :)**

```
<table width="600*" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr><br>
        <td width="201" valign="top"  >
            <img src="images/angebot1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0"              width="201" height="394"/><br />
            <br />
        </td>

        <td width="291" valign="top" style="background-color:#eee;">
            <img src="images/angebotbild1.jpg" style="display: block;" border="0" width="335" height="150"/>


 <div style="padding:30px;">The text</div>

            <br><br>
            <a  href="#" alt="Book now" target="_blank" style="color:#cc1f2f; font-weight:bold; text -decoration:none;float:left"><img src="images/button.jpg" width="335" height="60" style="display:block;" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```